# How to disable Listview Stretching on overscrolling

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I don't know if stretching is the correct word to describe it.
But it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ68P.png).
"last message " is the last message in this convo and the empty space below is the 'stretching'. Once I release the touch from my screen it goes back to [normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bi4s.png). I want to disable that 'stretching' so that nothing happens when the user overscrolls.

ListView code:

```
ListView.builder(
            controller: _controller1,
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,  //snapshot from parent StreamBuilder
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final allowedOrNot = index == 0
                  ? true
                  : compareDate(          // Userdefined function to check if the dates above messages should be displayed or not
                      currentSnap: snapshot.data!.docs[index]
                          .data()['serverTimeStamp'],
                      previousSnap: snapshot.data!.docs[index - 1]
                          .data()['serverTimeStamp']);
              return Column(
                children: [
                  allowedOrNot
                      ? chatDater(    // the date widget (above some messages to indicate the date of conversation)
                          data: dataForChatDater(  // Userdefined function which returns Strings like 'Yesterday', 'Today' for the widget to display
                              snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index]
                                  .data()['serverTimeStamp']),
                        )
                      : const SizedBox(
                          width: 0,
                          height: 0,
                        ),
                  Align(
                    alignment:
                        snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()['sender'] ==
                                widget.usernameOfFriend
                            ? Alignment.centerLeft
                            : Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: MessageBubble(  // The ChatBubble widget used to display the messages
                      timestamp: snapshot.data!.docs[index]
                          .data()['serverTimeStamp'],
                      message: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()['message'],
                      IsYou: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()['sender'] ==
                              widget.usernameOfFriend
                          ? false
                          : true,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the "stretching" effect [(`StretchingOverscrollIndicator`)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StretchingOverscrollIndicator-class.html) from happening, we need to wrap the `ListView.builder` inside `NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>` widget.

This widget gives a notification whenever over scroll happens and provides `onNotification` callback to handle the notification. Inside `onNotification` handler, we can use `disallowIndicator` to prevent any sort of indicator from showing.

The code would look something like this:

```dart
NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
            onNotification: (overscroll) {
              overscroll.disallowIndicator(); // Prevent Overscroll Indication
              return true;
            },
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text("Hi");
              },
              itemCount: data.length
            )
          )
```

Refer:

[OverscrollIndicatorNotification](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OverscrollIndicatorNotification-class.html)

[disallowIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OverscrollIndicatorNotification/disallowIndicator.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is natural behavior of `BouncingScrollPhysics`.

If you don't want to overscroll, you can change it to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`.

Comment: I still want to scroll among the messages, just not overscroll beyond those messages. `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` will make the list so that the user can never scroll, but I don't want that.

Comment: Then how about ```ClampingScrollPhysics```?

Answer (score 0):

Try `shrinkWrap:true` in your ListView.builder and `mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min` in `Column` as follows:

```
      ListView.builder(
      //other
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, //use this
          children: [
            //your children
          ],
        );
      })
```